# Is there a way to omit the prompt for deletion in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom

I'm here at the [Imagine Cup World Finals](http://bit.ly/fsx8fQ) again taking pictures, and I'm using Adobe Lightroom, and I took a large number of pictures today which are garbage. I'd like a quick way of going through those images and throwing out the absolute garbage (blurry, underexposed, overexposed, etc). However, every time I hit the delete key, Lightroom keeps complaining "Do you want to delete these or merely remove them from the catalog?" -- I want to just nuke them from the collection but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to tell it to always pick one option or another.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't believe you can disable it, but a really easy workflow in regards to this is:

- The photos you would delete, mark as 'Rejected' with the 'X' shortcut key.
- After you're all done, go to the grid view in Library, click the 'Rejected' flag to filter by rejected and delete them all in one go.

Comment: Even faster: Press Cmd+Backspace (probably Ctrl+Delete on Win) to automatically delete all rejected pictures ;)

Comment: @eWolf I've always liked having the option in bulk and ctrl+backspace may be a slight second faster, but for a huge group of pictures in one go, I'd rather it ask me.

Comment: In LR3, after rejecting your photos you don't have to change views.  Just go to the menu Photo -> Delete Rejected Photos (it's the last option).

Comment: @rfusca It still prompts you when you click Ctrl+Backspace.

Comment: Another refinement is to filter your grid view to show only flagged and unflagged (but not rejected) photos. Now when you hit X to reject a photo it'll disappear from view. When you're done, hit Ctrl/Cmd + Backspace: LR will now automatically switch the filter to only show rejected photos and prompt you to delete them. After you've done so, you're returned to your previous filter view: flagged & unflagged only. Perfect!

Comment: Mark's suggestion is perfect -- I wanted a single button press to not only mark for deletion but take the picture out of the current navigation, and that does it.

Comment: @Doug ya, thats what I do now.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac Option-Delete seems to Remove without prompting. Note it does Remove from collection, not "Delete from Disk". You said "nuke from collection" which makes me not 100% sure which you actually want :).

Personally I would like Delete from Disk, but I can't seem to find a combination that works for that.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can press Alt-Shift-Delete to remove the current photo from Lightroom. Unfortunately there isn't an equivalent keypress to remove them from the disk and the key combo likewise cannot delete a group of pictures at once.